# how can i active wazuh agent on windows , the manager is on an Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: agent, wazuh

i open VB with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.
and install wazuh all in one.
after i log in to the elastic and add agent the problem start.
It doesn't matter if I try to do it on another machine on my Windows or on a friend's Windows with a private network, it doesn't recognize the agent at all.
i try my public and Private ip and nuthing.

the agent code i do is :

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://packages.wazuh.com/4.x/windows/wazuh-agent-4.3.6-1.msi -OutFile ${env:tmp}\wazuh-agent-4.3.6.msi; msiexec.exe /i ${env:tmp}\wazuh-agent-4.3.6.msi /q WAZUH_MANAGER='localhost' WAZUH_REGISTRATION_SERVER='localhost' WAZUH_AGENT_GROUP='default'
```

and after :

```
NET START WazuhSvc
```

with my ip.And nothing happens.
Has anyone encountered this or can help?

Answer (score 0):

Checking your install and enrollment command we can see that you have
set the WAZUH_REGISTRATION_SERVER to localhost.
This should be replaced with your manager IP. In order to do that in a deployed Windows agent like your case change the configuration file (`C:\Program Files (x86)\ossec-agent\ossec.conf`) replacing the manager IP with the real one. For example:

```
<address>192.168.1.17</address>
```

Finally, restart your wazuh-agent.

In order to deploy and enroll new agents please remember to replace the localhost value with your real wazuh manager host in the Wazuh server address step.

Comment: Hi first of all Ty for the response. Of course I put my manager ip and not local host the problem is that nothing happens.. he is not show the agent active after it. And I don’t know why

Comment: Could you please share your agent's `ossec.log` file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should go to this folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ossec-agent
```

and run `win32ui` as an admin, then click manage and restart the agent.